# Extracting a matching pattern using Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

The use case is to extract strings which do not have any value populated in =(equal symbol)
eg: in the below example, given the input string:

```
something=na&rows[0][data]=0&rows[0][name]=&rows[0][indexable]=true&rows[0][searchable]=false&columns[0][search][value]=&
```

we would like to match the following

```
&rows[0][name]=
&columns[0][search][value]=
```

I tried using this regex `&(.*?)=&` , but the problem here is it matches something like this `&rows[0][data]=0&rows[0][name]=&` which is incorrect.It needs to match string `&rows[0][name]=`
Also would be helpful what do we call such searches in regex? (Positive lookahead?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negated character class with a positive lookahead:

```
&[^&=]+=(?=&)
```

The pattern matches

- `&` Match a & char
- `[^&=]+` Match 1+ times any char except `&` or `=`
- `=(?=&)` Match `=` asserting a `&` char directly to the right using a positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KWxJOw/1)

As an alternative without using a lookahead, you could also use capture group with a match for the following `&`:

```
(&[^&=]+=)&
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HRso4i/1)